# Using an AC Fan on DC Battery

Tags: batteries, ac-dc

I have a 30wp solar panel which charges a 28amp 12 V dc battery. Can I use an ac fan (with less power) on that battery? I am newbie to electronics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most AC fans have induction motors and as such won't work on DC. You will most likely need an **inverter**, to convert from 12VDC to the AC voltage that fan requires.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would you recommend an inventor for my situation and a small fan for max performance and max running time for this 28amp battery?

Comment: Normally I would look for some cheap device sold on eBay. However, I doubt you will find a cheap 12VDC to 12VAC inverter - they are generally 12DC to mains AC. Maybe a mains rated fan? You will also need to factor in the losses due to inefficient conversion

Comment: @Rizwan why not look for a PC fan, they are DC fans and you should only need a voltage regulator to get the 12V to what it needs

Comment: @Ratchetfreak:It might be a bit noisy but you should be able to get away with a PC fan or other 12V fan off a 12V nominal battery (e.g. a car battery).  A simple DC motor can handle quite a bit of over/under voltage (from what I've used in the past a PC fan can run from 7V and doesn't burn out in a hurry at 15V).  Alternatively a PC variable fan speed control might be a nice addition or a couple of small power diodes in series to drop the voltage.

Comment: Will they give enough air for single person on a cabin? I was looking for something like this: http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v3/243107702/dc_fan_12v_24v_WIN_101.jpg

Comment: @Rizwan You can find case fans at least as large as 200mm; which is probably larger than the fan you're looking at.  Alternately, you can mount multiple smaller ones in a frame to increase total airflow.

Comment: @Rizwan, that fan you linked to is a DC fan, the kind often used in trucks. How big is your cabin? How much air do you want to move in that cabin? I ask that last question because some people would want no fan at all, while others would want a windstorm.

Comment: lol... I don't want windstorm but something similar to that. Good for Summer in South Asia. And, my cabin is almost 5x6 ft